# including forms in hook_view

Tags: 6, hooks, forms

Is it possible to include forms and have it be submitted when viewing a node type?  A good example is the default 'Add Comment' module.  When you view a node, there is a link you need to click on to leave a comment.  This link essentially takes you to the comment form.  Is there any way to do like Youtube.com where you can have the comment form textarea box in the node view?  It just seems silly to have to make your users click a link to 'add comment'.

For example, the below does nothing in my custom module when viewing a node:

```
function Mymod_view($node,$teaser=false,$page=false) {
  $node->content['name'] = array(
    '#type' = 'textfield',
  );
  // hitting submit does nothing. NOTHING!
  $node->content['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => 'SUBMIT',
  );
  return $node;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create forms everywhere you want.

Your code adds form elements without a surrounding  element. That makes it useless.

Define your form in a separate function and call `drupal_get_form('your function name')` to make it working. See the [form generation doc](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--form.inc/group/form_api/7) for a full description.